# Windows NTSD Debugger

Tags: debugging

I am doing some debugging of a crash dump file using NTSD. Is it possible to redirect all the output that I am seeing on console now to a txt file? I am getting all the call stacks of all the threads however can't see that information in a debugger window.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the `.logopen` and `.logclose` commands.  You should be able to do `.logopen foo.txt`, issue your command (which I'm assuming is `~*k`), and then when it's done, do `.logclose`.